# Windows 10 Black Screen on shutdown/reboot

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I am experiencing a problem that was apparently common on Windows 10 at some point but has since gone away for most. Not for me however.

When I shut down or reboot windows 10, after the shutdown sequence completes the power remains on on my laptop but all the hardware turns off (screen is blank, keyboard LEDs turn off, etc, but the power leds & fans stay on) after this I have to hold the power button down to force it to complete the shutdown sequence.

I have tried all the recommended solutions I've dug up on google which includes:

- Disabling Fast Startup
- Disabling Fast Boot (BIOS) and CMS (set boot to UEFI only)
- Not allowing the system to turn off the Intel Management Engine Interface to save power
- Updating my graphics drivers (both of them are fully up to date) and BIOS
- Shutting down from the commandline (command prompt)
- Disabling Hibernation support in windows. (powercfg.exe /h off)

I'm running an MSI GE75 Raider 8SE laptop on Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC; Version 1809.

Additional info: Shutting down from safe mode works fine.

Comment: Have you tried updating the firmware of the BIOS to the latest version yet? If not, try that as well and test some more just in case it's a firmware bug with your hardware.

Comment: Are you on Windows 10 version 1903?

Comment: @harrymc I am on Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC; Version 1809.

Comment: Which part of the hardware does NOT turn off? Is it only the monitor (and which one is it)?

Comment: @harrymc there's no way for me to identify what stays on and what goes off. After shutdown the power led and battery charging led stay on (should both be off when the system is fully powered down) and that the only way to complete the shutdown is holding down the power button.

Comment: Do you mean that after holding down the power button the power and battery charging leds turn off?

Comment: @harrymc yes. Also I tried updating the BIOS to the latest version, it did not affect the issue.

Comment: Does this also happen when disconnecting all possible devices? You might try to see if the [Intel Driver & Support Assistant](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html) can find an update for your system.

Comment: @harrymc The only device plugged into my laptop is a mouse... I strongly doubt unplugging my mouse will achieve much. The intel driver assistant found outdated drivers for the bluetooth and intel igpu. Interesting about the latter considering I just updated it. I will try updating these but I doubt they will fix my issue too.

Comment: @harrymc nope, no effect.I even tried unplugging the mouse and ethernet cable too on the second attempt, just for the lulz, but it was still the same.

Comment: What happens when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc I booted into safe mode then shutdown the computer. In safe mode the shutdown was successful (indicating that there has to indeed be some kind of solution for this)

Comment: Does `shutdown /h` makes every devices turned off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As when booting in Safe mode the shutdown is successful and complete, this indicates
that some third-party application is responsible for the problem.

To locate the problematic application, you may use the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

This utility shows all programs configured to run during system bootup or login,
and when starting various built-in Windows applications such as
Internet Explorer, Explorer and media players.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them later with another click. You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*,
*Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*

I would suggest turning off startup entries in bunches, drilling down to the startup
program that causes this behavior. Once identified, it might have some setting
that can avoid the problem, or can be left out of startup and only be invoked
when required (verify that once invoked it does not add another startup
entry, but such can be deleted by Autoruns).

Comment: There's a problem with this theory, I've had this problem since my first boot, I installed this just a few days ago. I will humor you and try this though. But why would I need a third party program for this when I can see all this stuff in task manager?

Comment: You should then look mostly at products you have installed at the beginning. Please note that this includes third-party device drivers. Autoruns has a better interface that allows listing by type, search and undoing.

Comment: Yeah that rules out my antivirus at least. I just tried stopping every service & process that seemed even remotly likely to  be involved. Had no effect.Now I'm going to try just disabling everything through autoruns and see if that fixes it. But I strongly suspect that the cause is actually something on microsoft/windows's side rather than third parties.

Comment: Allright, you were on to something. After disabling everything from my vpn down to my keyboard driver, then restarted, something went right and it restarted normally. Now that just leaves one question. Is there any way to figure out the culprit other than trial and error?

Comment: Not that I know of, except for guessing.

Comment: Right,was worth a try. You've certainly earned the bounty, I can't award it till 30 minutes from now but you'll get it. Thanks for your help :) I'll tell you when I figure out what the culprit was.

Comment: After some digging I found that RTSUER (realtek usb card reader) driver was the problem... And the reason why it was breaking everything was because I have a MicroSD->SDCard adapter that I've left plugged in there for months (without any actual card in it) I was pretty sure I already tested to see if this was the cause of my problem but I clearly didn't check close enough. That solves the mystery I guess. The reason I never even begun to suspect it could mess anything up was because it's not actually a device, e.g. wasn't connected to anything, and on Linux this never caused any problems.

Comment: The Linux driver was apparently better-programmed, because what happened to you is a pretty weird effect for a simple driver.

Comment: Yeah it was quite bizarre. I also had an issue with Windows taking forever (literally 1-2 minutes) to boot up (I am using an NVME drive... Linux boots in like 3 seconds), but this issue was also the cause for the slow boot. Problematic to start, impossible to close. I do find it quite weird however that it didn't hang on the part where windows tells me it's shutting down/restarting but after it was supposed to be 'done'. While the driver certainly had problems though, I blame the windows kernel's error handling for this. I've had similar cases in the past (a hdd caddy and a usb switch).

Answer (score 0):

Do you boot from a legacy or UEFI disc, or did you try a hard shutdown by pressing on/off for at least 5 seconds?

Maybe you can try the following:

- The problem seems something to do with hibernation mode, that feature never worked very well.
- Try this command `shutdown /s /f /t 0`.
- Lock the screen then shutdown in the lower right corner
- Uncheck and check the power button setting again [image: Power Options => Power Buttons and Lid => Power Button Action => Setting = Shutdown]

Comment: That shutdown command did not help, but yes I agree it might have something to do with the hibernation feature.